# How to fetch '_' in Like in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with one column having data as text. There are some values starting with L_. How can I query it using LIKE.

I have tried

```
select * from testtable where data_name like 'L\_'
```

and also

```
select * from testtable where data_name like 'L__%'
```

but first one gives no data. Second query returns all the data starting with L.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: I've removed PL/SQL from the title and the tags. This question is not about Oracle's programming language PL/SQL, but about SQL. The underline is a wildcard character standing for a single character in `LIKE`. If you want to look for an underline in a string with `LIKE` you'll have to escape it as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `escape`.

```
select *
from testtable
where data_name like 'L\_%' escape '\';
```

For example:

```
SQL> with testtable (data_name) as
  2    (select 'Littlefoot' from dual union all
  3     select 'L_aibach'   from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from testtable
  7  where data_name like 'L\_%' escape '\';

DATA_NAME
----------
L_aibach

SQL>
```

---

More about it in any Oracle [`like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) documentation (this is the first Google returned).